# json does not have column names after resample pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to get column names when you are using to_json on resample data?

```
amount = df['amount'].resample('M').last()
amount = amount.to_json()
```

output that I'm getting:

```
{"1501459200000":1.79,"1504137600000":88.80}
```

output I want:

```
[{"time":"1501459200000","amount":1.79},{"time":"1504137600000","amount":88.80}]
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data?

Comment: Your expected JSON is invalid..

Comment: Do you need `amount.to_json(orient='records')` ?

Comment: @jezrael YES! Btw, The time is getting converted to epoch or iso with T00:00:00 . I don't want the time part only the date. But I'm not getting just the date! PLease can you tell me how can I get only date(same date format)? Thank You in Advance, Jezrael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter `orient='records'` in [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html), but if need only `dates` add [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), for rename index [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'amount': np.random.rand(10)}, 
                   index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=10, freq='20D'))

print (df)
              amount
2018-01-01  0.015710
2018-01-21  0.128403
2018-02-10  0.508626
2018-03-02  0.884921
2018-03-22  0.820198
2018-04-11  0.574304
2018-05-01  0.961553
2018-05-21  0.352586
2018-06-10  0.965337
2018-06-30  0.112810

amount = df['amount'].resample('M').last().rename_axis('time').reset_index()
amount['time'] = amount['time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
amount = amount.to_json(orient='records')
print (amount)

[{"time":"2018-01-31","amount":0.1284033196},
 {"time":"2018-02-28","amount":0.5086261293},
 {"time":"2018-03-31","amount":0.8201977996},
 {"time":"2018-04-30","amount":0.5743039198},
 {"time":"2018-05-31","amount":0.352586249},
 {"time":"2018-06-30","amount":0.1128097924}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON output is invalid, the closest thing to your format is as follows:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=100, freq='D'),
                     data={'data': np.random.rand(100)})
data.index.name = 'amount'
data.resample(' M').last().reset_index().to_json(orient='index')
```

**Output**

```
{"0":{"amount":1517356800000,"data":0.3235796421},
"1":{"amount":1519776000000,"data":0.0473271793},
"2":{"amount":1522454400000,"data":0.8382262681},
"3":{"amount":1525046400000,"data":0.6356939511}}
```

Comment: Awesome! Works :)